# add contents to list after a occusrance of a symbol in python

Tags: python, grep

I have the following data.

```
1
abc
>
2
def
efg
>
3
hij
jkl
>
4
mno
5
pqr
stu
```

I want all the contents to be added to a list after each occurrence of '>' and number say '3'.

output should be like

```
[[abc],[[def],[efg]],[[hij],[jkl]],[mno],[[pqr],[stu]]]
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please post _your_ code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the items are in a list L

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, ">0123456789".__contains__) if not k]
[['abc'], ['def', 'efg'], ['hij', 'jkl'], ['mno'], ['pqr', 'stu']]
```

It's not exactly the right format, because your format isn't valid python. But should get you started

Answer (score 0):

If you using file to store the information, you could use the following approach:

```
result = []

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:

    # Read file line by line
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()

        # Ignore '>' or numbers         
        if line == '>' or line.isdigit():
            continue
        result.append([line])

print(result)
```